# Use variables in manifest

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, branch.io

Integrating some libraries like `Branch-io` in Android need to define meta-data in the project manifest. some of these variables are like `TestMode`

```
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true" />
```

So, when we want to publish the application we should change it to False.

Is there any way to define a variable somewhere according to `BuildType` and assign it to the Meta-data to that?

Answer (score 14):

You can do it by adding [manifestPlaceholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables) to your **build.gradle** file:

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            manifestPlaceholders = [isBranchSdkInTestMode:"true"]
            ...
        }
        release {
            manifestPlaceholders = [isBranchSdkInTestMode:"false"]
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

In **AndroidManifest.xml**, you can use it as `${isBranchSdkInTestMode}`:

```xml
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="${isBranchSdkInTestMode}" />
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes you can inject build variables from gradle to manifest, it is done by adding variable to the `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.example.com"]
    }
    deployConfg {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.prod-server.com"]
    }
    ...
}
```

And then in your manifest you can get it by:

```
<intent-filter ... >
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="${hostName}" ... />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```

You can read more about how this works [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables).